# Pasting native HTML to browser clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard

With a button click, a user will have HTML content from the current page into the clipboard. Then, in an email, paste the content with the HTML formatting preserved. The desire is to replicate the selecting of content in the browser window, without making the user do the selecting (separate view).

I have most of this setup and working. I don't believe there are permissions issues. However, with the below code, I get "pasted", yet then pasting (CTRL+V) following that, there is nothing in the paste buffer. If I switch it to `clipboard.writeText()`, I get the html as plaintext. It's just using the `Blob` for html that causes the paste buffer to be empty.

I think it relates to the `Blob` part, maybe the `text/html` part is wrong? Is there a way to get this to work?

```
<div id="lipsum" contenteditable="true" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Vivamus mollis, augue eu vulputate fermentum.</p>
</div>
<script>
(function() {
  let html = document.getElementById('lipsum').innerHTML
  let content = new Blob([ html ], { type: 'text/html' })
  let data = [ new ClipboardItem({ [ content.type ]: content }) ]
  
  window.focus()

  setTimeout(() => {
    navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(
      () => console.log('pasted'),                   <<< This fires
      (error) => console.log('not pasted', error)
    )
  }, 2000)
})()
</script>
```

Comment: I can replicate the issue with `text/html` using an event listener and changing the clipboard data content type to `text/html`. Must be something to that quirk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked for me on Chrome. I was able to paste the div contents after loading the page and waiting a couple seconds. I did notice errors if I didn't continuously have the page focused. E.g. when I would keep the inspector window forward it would error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lipsum" contenteditable="true" style="display: none;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Vivamus mollis, augue eu vulputate fermentum.</p>
</div>

<script>
  (function() {
    let html = document.getElementById('lipsum').innerHTML
    let content = new Blob([ html ], { type: 'text/plain' })
    let data = [ new ClipboardItem({ [ content.type ]: content }) ]

    setTimeout(() => {
      window.focus()
      navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(
        () => console.log('pasted'),
        (error) => console.log('not pasted', error)
      )
    }, 2000)
  })()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, i think I just figured out Synergy (keyboard/mouse share) is stripping the html.

Comment: I made something like this a ways back and it ways a bit problematic cross browser/environment. There is always something like https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: Yep, that was it (copying to another machine must have stripped the html-related clipboard content).

Comment: Late to the party, but I don't quite understand this solution. The original question specified 'text/html' as the MIME type, and the issue seems to be coming from that. In this answer, the MIME type is changed to 'text/plain'. That works fine (when pasting you get the HTML tags verbatim, you're not pasting formatted content) but that wasn't really the intent of the original question, was it? Did I miss something?